# How to configure PostgreSQL for best access from both Windows 7 host and Ubuntu 12.04 guest?

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, postgresql

I have a new Ubuntu 12.04 installation freshly installed on VirtualBox, which in turn is running on a 64 bit Windows 7 machine with plenty of RAM. I would like to install PostgreSQL on this system in such a way that the data in that database can be accessed from either the virtual Linux machine or the actual Windows machine. In both cases I want to be able to access the database using either a general purpose SQL interface (like pgAdmin III) and also from a machine-specific installation of the R statistical language using the RPostgreSQL DBI. As of this moment I do not expect to make the database available to any other computers, except, perhaps, my laptop.

This will be my first attempt to install a database on a virtual machine. Am I right that to do this I would do a separate PostgreSQL installation on each machine, but have both of them point to the same data directory? If not, could someone suggest the most sensible configuration for the purposes I have stated? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I right that to do this I would do a separate PostgreSQL installation on each machine, but have both of them point to the same data directory?

Absolutely not, no. PostgreSQL cannot share a data directory between multiple running postmasters, nor are data directories compatible between different PostgreSQL versions or builds of PostgreSQL on different operating systems / architectures.

You install the PostgreSQL server on one of them. You set `listen_addresses` to allow non-local TCP/IP connections, probably by setting it to `*`. Then you use the PostgreSQL client applications and libraries to *connect to* the server over TCP/IP from both machines after using your VM system's usual features to enable networking betwen guest and host, and by making appropriate openings in the firewall on the machine running the server.

You'll need to modify `pg_hba.conf` to permit connections from remote hosts too. See the "client authentication" chapter of the documentation.

Comment: Thanks, Craig. Two quick questions: 1. With the configuration you describe, does it matter at all which machine I do the install on? 2. If I let each machine have its own copy of the data set, can I run both on the same physical machine?

Comment: It doens't really matter which you install on. It's just a client/server setup either way. And yeah, you can have two independent servers just fine if you clone the data set, after all, they're VMs.